# How to get data from Appsync using identity provider's sessionToken?

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, graphql, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am kind of confused with the whole thing. Let me try to put this way.
1. Can I fetch data from appsync using `sessionToken` which provides

```
final _credential = new CognitoCredentials(_identityPoolId, _userPool);
await _credential.getAwsCredentials(token, 'graph.facebook.com');
print(_credential.sessionToken);
```

I am using dart, flutter to do this. According to [this](https://github.com/zino-app/graphql-flutter/issues/209#issuecomment-598835690) looks like possible but only via JWT? Are JWT and identity pool's sessiosToken are completely different things?

If that's the case is it possible to fetch the data from appsync sessionToken?

If data fetching is not possible with sessionToken, how do I connect the identity pool to user pool? Each time user logs in I have to update the userpool (like [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-integrating-user-pools-with-identity-pools.html), any better example)? After adding the user to userpool I can able to fetch the JWT token using `_session.getIdToken().getJwtToken()`?

Any help would be great :) I am stuck with this to fetch data from appsync for days now. :(

Comment: A session token is just part of the temporary AWS credentials that Cognito Federated Identity pools provide when you federate via an external identity provider such as Facebook for example. By itself, it does not provide any information, but could populate some context data when used against some AWS services. JWT tokens are based 64 encoded tokens provided by OIDC compliant providers (such as Cognito user pools). They can be decoded and they contain claims such as some user data. Not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve but hope this helps.

Comment: So the idea of data is to get data from appsync. I am using aws-amplify and api as graphql with auth. So get data only authenticated users. Now to get data from appsync endpoint it needs a jwt token as amplify doesn't have support for Flutter at the moment.
So to get the JWT token I was using  https://github.com/furaiev/amazon-cognito-identity-dart-2 to login, but this doesn't support social login for cognito.